# How can I work with arrays and json objects within the laravel framework?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I have imported an SQL file into my database and have migrated it as such...

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('pokemon', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->json('types');
            $table->string('height');
            $table->string('weight');
            $table->json('abilities');
            $table->json('eggGroups');
            $table->json('stats');
            $table->string('genus');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->boolean('captured');
        });
    }
```

The issue I am having is utilizing the "abilities" and "stats" tables, since those were imported as array and object. I would like to be able to utilize the arrays and objects from those tables in my frontend. How can I properly serve those through my API. Right now, all I'm getting back are strings that look like arrays/objects.

Pokemon resource

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Pokemon extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'types' => $this->types,
            'height' => $this->height,
            'weight' => $this->weight,
            'abilities' => $this->abilities,
            'eggGroups' => $this->eggGroups,
            'stats' => $this->stats,
            'genus' => $this->genus,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'captured' => $this->captured,
        ];
    }
};
```

Pokemon controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Models\Pokemon;
use App\Http\Resources\Pokemon as PokemonResource;

class PokemonController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $searched_pokemon = Pokemon::where('name', 'LIKE', ("%" . $request->input('name') . "%"))->paginate(12);
        return PokemonResource::collection($searched_pokemon);
    }
}
```

[Image of the sql database entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnpLJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use Attribute casting in laravel
[Array & JSON casting](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting).

Comment: Please add some example code to the answer, link only answers may become useless if the resource linked to is moved or deleted.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, IMHO the answer gives very little information as to how to solve it - just a link to a page which will help.  It may solve it if you know about what he is talking about, but as I don't - I wouldn't be able to solve the problem without having to look further.